# Ternary search recursion isn't correct

Tags: algorithm, search

I learned about ternary search from Wikipedia. I'm not sure what they mean by the parameter absolute precision. They didn't elaborate. But here is the pseudocode:

```
def ternarySearch(f, left, right, absolutePrecision):
    #left and right are the current bounds; the maximum is between them
    if (right - left) < absolutePrecision:
        return (left + right)/2

    leftThird = (2*left + right)/3
    rightThird = (left + 2*right)/3

    if f(leftThird) < f(rightThird):
        return ternarySearch(f, leftThird, right, absolutePrecision)

    return ternarySearch(f, left, rightThird, absolutePrecision)
```

I want to find max value from a unimodal function. That means I want to print the border point of the increasing and decreasing sequence. If the sequence is

```
1 2 3 4 5 -1 -2 -3 -4
```

then I want to print 5 as output.

Here is my attempt. It isn't giving output. Can you please help or give me link that contains good tutorial on ternary search for self learning?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int ternary_search(int[], int, int, int);
int precval = 1;

int main()
{
    int n, arr[100], target;
    cout << "\t\t\tTernary Search\n\n" << endl;
    //cout << "This program will find max element in an unidomal array." << endl;
    cout << "How many integers: "; 
    cin >> n;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];
    cout << endl << "The max number in the array is: ";
    int res = ternary_search(arr,0,n-1,precval)+0;
    cout << res << endl;
    return 0;
}

int ternary_search(int arr[], int left, int right, int precval)
{
    if (right-left <= precval)
        return (arr[right] > arr[left]) ? arr[right] : arr[left];
    int first_third = (left * 2 + right) / 3;
    int last_third = (left + right * 2) / 3;
    if(arr[first_third] < arr[last_third])
        return ternary_search(arr, first_third, right, precval);
    else
        return ternary_search(arr, left, last_third, precval);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Absolute precision means the maximum error between the returned result and the true result i.e. `max | returned_result - true_result |`. In that context, `f` is a continuous function.

Since you are looking at a discrete function, you can't do much better than get to the point where `right - left <= 1`. Then, just compare the two resultant values and return the value corresponding to the larger one (since you're looking for `max`).

**EDIT**

The first partition point, being mathematically `2/3*left + right/3`, should be discretized to `ceil(2/3*left + right/3)` (so that the relationship is `left < first_third <= last_third < right`

So `first_third = (left*2+right)/3` should be changed to `first_third = (left*2 + right + 2)/3`.

Comment: >Since you are looking at a discrete function, you can't do much better than get to the >point where right - left <= 1. Then, just compare the two resultant values and return the >value corresponding to the larger one (since you're looking for max).

Thank you, I edited the code writing

if(right-left<=precval) //I decleared 'precval' a global variable having value 1 return (arr[right]>arr[left])?arr[right]:arr[left];

but it also doesn't give any output.

Comment: can you edit your question to include the changes? when I trace by hand, it works (the last recursive call has `(left, right) = (4, 5)`.

Comment: Here is what happened: In ternary search when there are <=3 values left you have to handle it in base case. Otherwise it may cause stack overflow because function with same parameter is called again and again.[Remember in binary search base case is when <=2 values are left]

Example: N = 3
values are 0 2 1
first call-> ternary_search(arr, 0, 2)
first_third = 0 // observe left and first_third has become same, so you have to handle this as a base case i.e. right-left<=2 is base case.
second_third = 1

arr[first_third] < arr[second_third]

So you again call ternary_search(arr, 0, 2)

Comment: I see. Yes that reasoning of the second half of your comment is right.

Comment: oh you are right. um. actually the other way of solving it is to compute the thirds in another way... i'll edit my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try Golden Section search (or Fibonacci search for discrete functions).
It has a smaller number of recursions AND a 50% reduction in evaluations of f, compared to the above ternary search.